# How can I use TestScheduler with ReplaySubject time windowed

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an example of test code:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_only_contain_most_recent() {
        var window = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        var results = new ReplaySubject<long>(window);
        results.OnNext(1);
        results.OnNext(2);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        results.OnNext(3);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        results.OnNext(4);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        results.OnNext(5);
        results.OnCompleted();
        var items = results.ToEnumerable();
        Assert.True(items.SequenceEqual(new long [] { 5 }));
    }
```

which I would like to turn into using the TestScheduler from Microsoft.Reactive.Testing package, because I would like to get rid of the sleeps here.

I have already tried to do something like that.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Should_only_contain_most_recent() {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var window = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
        var results = new ReplaySubject<long>(window /* Never finishes when add the scheduler here.*/);
        results.OnNext(1);
        results.OnNext(2);
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () => results.OnNext(3));
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () => results.OnNext(4));
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), () => results.OnNext(5));
        scheduler.Schedule(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(210), results.OnCompleted);
        scheduler.Start();

        var items = results.ToEnumerable();
        Assert.True(items.SequenceEqual(new long[] { 5 }));
    }
```

But I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are trying to test the replay behaviour of ReplaySubject. The problem is that you need to start the TestScheduler twice. It only runs until all scheduled events have been executed - but we need to load up the `ReplaySubject` without any subscriber so that it has the events it will replay - and then run the scheduler again once a subscriber attached.

Here's an idiomatic way to write this test:

First I set `source` up with the events we need. By deriving your test class from `ReactiveTest` you can take advantage of the OnXXX helper methods to create the source events more easily.

Once we have the source stream ready, we can subscribe the `ReplaySubject` to this and call `Start` on the `TestScheduler`. This will run the virtual time up to the last scheduled event (T=300ms) - which I demonstrate by dumping the time out.

Now we use the `TestScheduler`'s `CreateObserver` method to create a recorder for the results and subscribe this to the `ReplaySubject`.

Now we start the `TestScheduler` again - this runs the clock on from T=300ms until the newly minted scheduled events are flushed. These are the events the `ReplaySubject` needs to replay - those within the 200ms window. Note that these will be emited at T=300ms + 1 tick, + 2 ticks, and + 3 ticks - this is because the `TestScheduler` has a 1 tick resolution.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyTests : ReactiveTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Should_only_contain_most_recent()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var source = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
            OnNext(0, 1),
            OnNext(0, 2),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50).Ticks, 3),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100).Ticks, 4),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks, 5),
            OnCompleted(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks, witness: 0));

        var replaySubject = new ReplaySubject<int>(
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), scheduler);

        source.Subscribe(replaySubject);

        scheduler.Start();

        /* the test scheduler is now at 300 milliseconds
            * and the ReplaySubject is loaded */
        Console.WriteLine(scheduler.Now.Ticks);

        var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();
        replaySubject.Subscribe(results);

        /* run the scheduler on to flush the events from the ReplaySubject */
        scheduler.Start();

        results.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks + 1, 4),
            OnNext(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks + 2, 5),
            OnCompleted(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300).Ticks + 3, witness: 0));
    }
}
```